# Class member is null in another method returning value from the first one

Tags: php, class, class-members

I am having trouble to understand why the class member cannot carry forward the assigned/return value from one method to another.

> How exactly I should use the class member/s so it will be available
>   throughout the class and instance/object.

**`var_dump($this->taxonomies)` returns `NULL`**

```
class Btc_Taxonomy {

    public $taxonomies;
    public $taxonomy;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function get_registered_taxonomies() {

        $args = [];

        $taxonomies_object = get_taxonomies( $args, 'objects' );


        foreach ( $taxonomies_object as $taxonomy_object ) {

            $this->taxonomies[ $taxonomy_object->name ]['name']         = $taxonomy_object->name;
            $this->taxonomies[ $taxonomy_object->name ]['label']        = $taxonomy_object->label;
            $this->taxonomies[ $taxonomy_object->name ]['hierarchical'] = $taxonomy_object->hierarchical;
        }

        return $this->taxonomies;
    }

    public function get_taxonomies_dropdown( $name = 'btc_taxonomies', $class = 'btc-dropdown', $echo = true ) {

        $dropdown = '<select name="' . $name . '" class="' . $class . '">';
        $dropdown .= '<option value="">Select a taxonomy</option>';

        foreach ( $this->taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $dropdown .= '<option value="' . $taxonomy['name'] . '">' . $taxonomy['label'] . '</option>';
        }

        $dropdown .= '</select>';

        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $dropdown;
        } else {
            return $dropdown;
        }
    }

}
```

### Debug result

This is the output for `$taxonomies_object` in `get_registered_taxonomies()`

```
Array
(
    [category] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => category
            [label] => Categories
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Categories
                    [singular_name] => Category
                    [search_items] => Search Categories
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => All Categories
                    [parent_item] => Parent Category
                    [parent_item_colon] => Parent Category:
                    [edit_item] => Edit Category
                    [view_item] => View Category
                    [update_item] => Update Category
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Category
                    [new_item_name] => New Category Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                    [not_found] => No categories found.
                    [no_terms] => No categories
                    [items_list_navigation] => Categories list navigation
                    [items_list] => Categories list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Categories
                    [menu_name] => Categories
                    [name_admin_bar] => category
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 1
            [publicly_queryable] => 1
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [show_in_menu] => 1
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 1
            [show_tagcloud] => 1
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 1
            [show_admin_column] => 1
            [meta_box_cb] => post_categories_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_checkboxes
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_categories
                    [edit_terms] => edit_categories
                    [delete_terms] => delete_categories
                    [assign_terms] => assign_categories
                )

            [rewrite] => Array
                (
                    [with_front] => 1
                    [hierarchical] => 1
                    [ep_mask] => 512
                    [slug] => category
                )

            [query_var] => category_name
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 1
            [rest_base] => categories
            [rest_controller_class] => WP_REST_Terms_Controller
            [_builtin] => 1
        )

    [post_tag] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => post_tag
            [label] => Tags
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Tags
                    [singular_name] => Tag
                    [search_items] => Search Tags
                    [popular_items] => Popular Tags
                    [all_items] => All Tags
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => Edit Tag
                    [view_item] => View Tag
                    [update_item] => Update Tag
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Tag
                    [new_item_name] => New Tag Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => Separate tags with commas
                    [add_or_remove_items] => Add or remove tags
                    [choose_from_most_used] => Choose from the most used tags
                    [not_found] => No tags found.
                    [no_terms] => No tags
                    [items_list_navigation] => Tags list navigation
                    [items_list] => Tags list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Tags
                    [menu_name] => Tags
                    [name_admin_bar] => post_tag
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 1
            [publicly_queryable] => 1
            [hierarchical] => 
            [show_ui] => 1
            [show_in_menu] => 1
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 1
            [show_tagcloud] => 1
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 1
            [show_admin_column] => 1
            [meta_box_cb] => post_tags_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_input
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_post_tags
                    [edit_terms] => edit_post_tags
                    [delete_terms] => delete_post_tags
                    [assign_terms] => assign_post_tags
                )

            [rewrite] => Array
                (
                    [with_front] => 1
                    [hierarchical] => 
                    [ep_mask] => 1024
                    [slug] => tag
                )

            [query_var] => tag
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 1
            [rest_base] => tags
            [rest_controller_class] => WP_REST_Terms_Controller
            [_builtin] => 1
        )

    [nav_menu] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => nav_menu
            [label] => Navigation Menus
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Navigation Menus
                    [singular_name] => Navigation Menu
                    [search_items] => Search Tags
                    [popular_items] => Popular Tags
                    [all_items] => Navigation Menus
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => Edit Tag
                    [view_item] => View Tag
                    [update_item] => Update Tag
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Tag
                    [new_item_name] => New Tag Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => Separate tags with commas
                    [add_or_remove_items] => Add or remove tags
                    [choose_from_most_used] => Choose from the most used tags
                    [not_found] => No tags found.
                    [no_terms] => No tags
                    [items_list_navigation] => Tags list navigation
                    [items_list] => Tags list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Tags
                    [menu_name] => Navigation Menus
                    [name_admin_bar] => Navigation Menu
                    [archives] => Navigation Menus
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 
            [publicly_queryable] => 
            [hierarchical] => 
            [show_ui] => 
            [show_in_menu] => 
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 
            [show_tagcloud] => 
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 
            [show_admin_column] => 
            [meta_box_cb] => post_tags_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_input
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => nav_menu_item
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_categories
                    [edit_terms] => manage_categories
                    [delete_terms] => manage_categories
                    [assign_terms] => edit_posts
                )

            [rewrite] => 
            [query_var] => 
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 
            [rest_base] => 
            [rest_controller_class] => 
            [_builtin] => 1
        )

    [link_category] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => link_category
            [label] => Link Categories
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Link Categories
                    [singular_name] => Link Category
                    [search_items] => Search Link Categories
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => All Link Categories
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => Edit Link Category
                    [view_item] => View Tag
                    [update_item] => Update Link Category
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Link Category
                    [new_item_name] => New Link Category Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                    [not_found] => No tags found.
                    [no_terms] => No tags
                    [items_list_navigation] => Tags list navigation
                    [items_list] => Tags list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Link Categories
                    [menu_name] => Link Categories
                    [name_admin_bar] => Link Category
                    [archives] => All Link Categories
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 
            [publicly_queryable] => 
            [hierarchical] => 
            [show_ui] => 1
            [show_in_menu] => 1
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 
            [show_tagcloud] => 1
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 1
            [show_admin_column] => 
            [meta_box_cb] => post_tags_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_input
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => link
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_links
                    [edit_terms] => manage_links
                    [delete_terms] => manage_links
                    [assign_terms] => manage_links
                )

            [rewrite] => 
            [query_var] => 
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 
            [rest_base] => 
            [rest_controller_class] => 
            [_builtin] => 1
        )

    [post_format] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => post_format
            [label] => Formats
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Formats
                    [singular_name] => Format
                    [search_items] => Search Tags
                    [popular_items] => Popular Tags
                    [all_items] => Formats
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => Edit Tag
                    [view_item] => View Tag
                    [update_item] => Update Tag
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Tag
                    [new_item_name] => New Tag Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => Separate tags with commas
                    [add_or_remove_items] => Add or remove tags
                    [choose_from_most_used] => Choose from the most used tags
                    [not_found] => No tags found.
                    [no_terms] => No tags
                    [items_list_navigation] => Tags list navigation
                    [items_list] => Tags list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Tags
                    [menu_name] => Formats
                    [name_admin_bar] => Format
                    [archives] => Formats
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 1
            [publicly_queryable] => 1
            [hierarchical] => 
            [show_ui] => 
            [show_in_menu] => 
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 1
            [show_tagcloud] => 
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 
            [show_admin_column] => 
            [meta_box_cb] => post_tags_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_input
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_categories
                    [edit_terms] => manage_categories
                    [delete_terms] => manage_categories
                    [assign_terms] => edit_posts
                )

            [rewrite] => Array
                (
                    [with_front] => 1
                    [hierarchical] => 
                    [ep_mask] => 0
                    [slug] => type
                )

            [query_var] => post_format
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 
            [rest_base] => 
            [rest_controller_class] => 
            [_builtin] => 1
        )

    [product_group] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => product_group
            [label] => Product Groups
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Product Groups
                    [singular_name] => Product Group
                    [search_items] => Search Types
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => All Product Groups
                    [parent_item] => Parent Product Group
                    [parent_item_colon] => Parent Product Group:
                    [edit_item] => Edit Product Group
                    [view_item] => View Category
                    [update_item] => Update Product Group
                    [add_new_item] => Make Product Group
                    [new_item_name] => New Product Group Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                    [not_found] => No categories found.
                    [no_terms] => No categories
                    [items_list_navigation] => Categories list navigation
                    [items_list] => Categories list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Categories
                    [menu_name] => Product Groups
                    [name_admin_bar] => Product Group
                    [archives] => All Product Groups
                )

            [description] => Add product groups
            [public] => 1
            [publicly_queryable] => 1
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [show_in_menu] => 1
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 
            [show_tagcloud] => 
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 1
            [show_admin_column] => 1
            [meta_box_cb] => post_categories_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_checkboxes
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_categories
                    [edit_terms] => manage_categories
                    [delete_terms] => manage_categories
                    [assign_terms] => edit_posts
                )

            [rewrite] => Array
                (
                    [with_front] => 1
                    [hierarchical] => 
                    [ep_mask] => 0
                    [slug] => product-group
                )

            [query_var] => product_group
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 1
            [rest_base] => 
            [rest_controller_class] => 
            [_builtin] => 
        )

    [job_type] => WP_Taxonomy Object
        (
            [name] => job_type
            [label] => Types
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Types
                    [singular_name] => Type
                    [search_items] => Search Types
                    [popular_items] => Popular Types
                    [all_items] => Types
                    [parent_item] => Parent Type
                    [parent_item_colon] => Parent Type:
                    [edit_item] => Edit Type
                    [view_item] => View Type
                    [update_item] => Update Type
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Type
                    [new_item_name] => New Type Name
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => Separate Types with commas
                    [add_or_remove_items] => Add or remove Types
                    [choose_from_most_used] => Choose from most used Types
                    [not_found] => No Types Found
                    [no_terms] => No categories
                    [items_list_navigation] => Categories list navigation
                    [items_list] => Categories list
                    [most_used] => Most Used
                    [back_to_items] => ← Back to Categories
                    [menu_name] => Types
                    [name_admin_bar] => Type
                    [archives] => Types
                )

            [description] => 
            [public] => 1
            [publicly_queryable] => 1
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [show_in_menu] => 1
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 1
            [show_tagcloud] => 1
            [show_in_quick_edit] => 1
            [show_admin_column] => 
            [meta_box_cb] => post_categories_meta_box
            [meta_box_sanitize_cb] => taxonomy_meta_box_sanitize_cb_checkboxes
            [object_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => job
                )

            [cap] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [manage_terms] => manage_categories
                    [edit_terms] => manage_categories
                    [delete_terms] => manage_categories
                    [assign_terms] => edit_posts
                )

            [rewrite] => Array
                (
                    [with_front] => 
                    [hierarchical] => 
                    [ep_mask] => 0
                    [slug] => job_type
                )

            [query_var] => job_type
            [update_count_callback] => 
            [show_in_rest] => 
            [rest_base] => 
            [rest_controller_class] => 
            [_builtin] => 
            [show_tag_cloud] => 1
            [sort] => 
        )

)
```

This is the output of `$this->taxonomies` in `get_registered_taxonomies()` printed just before return it.

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [name] => category
            [label] => Categories
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

    [post_tag] => Array
        (
            [name] => post_tag
            [label] => Tags
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [nav_menu] => Array
        (
            [name] => nav_menu
            [label] => Navigation Menus
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [link_category] => Array
        (
            [name] => link_category
            [label] => Link Categories
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [post_format] => Array
        (
            [name] => post_format
            [label] => Formats
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [product_group] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_group
            [label] => Product Groups
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

    [job_type] => Array
        (
            [name] => job_type
            [label] => Types
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

)
```

This is what I get when I print `$this->tasonomies` in `get_taxonomies_dropdown() {` just after opening brace

```
NULL
```

This is what I get when I print `$this->get_registered_taxonomies()` in `get_taxonomies_dropdown() {` just after opening brace

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [name] => category
            [label] => Categories
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

    [post_tag] => Array
        (
            [name] => post_tag
            [label] => Tags
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [nav_menu] => Array
        (
            [name] => nav_menu
            [label] => Navigation Menus
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [link_category] => Array
        (
            [name] => link_category
            [label] => Link Categories
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [post_format] => Array
        (
            [name] => post_format
            [label] => Formats
            [hierarchical] => 
        )

    [product_group] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_group
            [label] => Product Groups
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

    [job_type] => Array
        (
            [name] => job_type
            [label] => Types
            [hierarchical] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Give an example where it does not work

Comment: `get_registered_taxonomies()` returns the value in `$this->taxonomies` and I am calling that memeber in function below it called `get_taxonomies_dropdown()` and it is giving NULL

Comment: @B001ᛦ it is loading on the WordPress plugin settings page using `add_action('admin_menu', ...)` hook. If using the method in the foreach loop, it is working fine but the direct class member is giving `NULL`

Comment: Your code looks good. Are you sure that get_taxonomies() is returning values?

Comment: @user1309690 Yes, it is returning value. I have checked and if I use the method in foreach instead of member it is working.

Comment: @user1309690 please have a look the output

Comment: This looks good. Are you using the same object of Btc_Taxonomy to call both Class Function.

Comment: @user1309690 actually I am not hooking this class method anywhere but using as an object to load dropdown field on the settings page. So technically, it should work. I believe the issue is somewhere in the class member. I am doing something wrong over there because method is returning value properly and populating dropdown but the class member.

Comment: @CodeLover Created a Demo for you, check this if its helpful. https://3v4l.org/Wn5pa

Comment: @user1309690 thanks a lot. I have tried without returning `$this->taxonomies` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose. You forgot initialize `$this->taxonomies` array, before calling method `get_taxonomies_dropdown`. For fixing this problem you should call `$this->get_registered_taxonomies()` before building options of dropdown or add calling `$this->get_registered_taxonomies()` in contructor of class

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Try to modify __contructor method.   `public function __construct() {
        $this->get_registered_taxonomies();
    }`